# add a temporary column with a value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a select statement like this

```
select field1, field2  
  from table1
```

What I want is to have a newfield with only value "example".

`newfield` does not exist in the table, but when I run this query it kinda makes a virtual column with the values of example field.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
select field1, field2, 'example' as TempField
from table1
```

This should work across different SQL implementations.

Comment: What if you want that TempField to contain a constant value ? like "Dummy String"

Comment: That's exactly what the above does.

Answer (score 27):

You mean staticly define a value, like this:

```
SELECT field1, 
       field2,
       'example' AS newfield
  FROM TABLE1
```

This will add a column called "newfield" to the output, and its value will always be "example".

Answer (score 8):

I'm rusty on SQL but I think you could use select as to make your own temporary query columns.

```
select field1, field2, 'example' as newfield from table1
```

That would only exist in your query results, of course. You're not actually modifying the table.

Answer (score 5):

In this example, the TABLE registrofaena doesn't have the column called ***minutos***. The query returns a column "minutos" with demora/60 as the content (the values represent the delay in minutes). The table is not modified in the process.

This is the query:

```
SELECT idfaena,fechahora,demora, demora/60 as minutos,comentario 
FROM registrofaena  
WHERE fecha>='2018-10-17' AND comentario <> '' 
ORDER BY idfaena ASC;
```

This is the view:

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 2):

```
select field1, field2, NewField = 'example' from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select field1, field2, '' as newfield from table1
```

This Will Do you Job