# Add a new column with a value to the select query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, eloquent

I would like to know how to create a default variable called "type" and set a value to "car" while doing a select join in Laravel.

Here is my code so far:

```
$items = DB::table('items')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                           ->join('items_categories', 'items.item_category_id', '=', 'items_categories.category_id')
                           ->select( 
                                     'items.id as items___item_id',
                                     'items.item_title as items___item_title',
                                     'items_categories.id as items_categories___category_id',
                                     'items_categories.title as items_categories___category_title',
                                   )
                           ->take(20);
```

This works nice. However, I need to get/add a custom key and value for each record of this select so I can use it later in the template to filter stuff further.

So, I need to add a key called `type` with a value of `car` so in the print_r I will see type => car for every record and I can use this in my code.

How to do that?

Can I put that somhow in the select?

Like:

```
->select( 
           'items.id as items___item_id',
           'items.item_title as items___item_title',
           'items_categories.id as items_categories___category_id',
           'items_categories.title as items_categories___category_title',
           //something like this?
           'type' = 'car'
        )
```

Because right now I am getting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [items___item_id] => 10
            [items___item_user_id] => 2
            [items___item_title] => A new blue truck
            [items_categories___category_id] => 1
            [items_categories___category_title] => Truck
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [items___item_id] => 11
            [items___item_user_id] => 2
            [items___item_title] => VW Tiguan
            [items_categories___category_id] => 1
            [items_categories___category_title] => SUV
        )
```

And I want to get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [items___item_id] => 10
            [items___item_user_id] => 2
            [items___item_title] => A new blue truck
            [items_categories___category_id] => 1
            [items_categories___category_title] => Truck
            [type] => car
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [items___item_id] => 11
            [items___item_user_id] => 2
            [items___item_title] => VW Tiguan
            [items_categories___category_id] => 1
            [items_categories___category_title] => SUV
            [type] => car
        )
```

If possible, not in the model file, but during the one query, because it's only one time when I need this modification to be done.

Comment: Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using Eloquent?

Comment: And do you want to do your select based on a type, e.g. `car`?

Comment: @RikardOlsson I want to create a new virtual column called `type` (this collumn doesn't exist in the database) on the fly during the select statement and assign all values in that field to `car` (for all results).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. In your query result you want to, on the fly, add a new "column" with a value and then assign this result to a model you call Car?

Comment: @RikardOlsson maybe somthing like this? `select "car" as type from items` ? But how to do that in Laravel?

Comment: @RikardOlsson check my updated question, please. I have added what I want to get as an output.

Comment: @RikardOlsson I have solved it myself ;) Check my answer

Answer (score 42):

You can use this method:

```
$data = DB::table('items')
   ->Select('items.id as items___item_id',
            'items.item_title as items___item_title');

# Add fake column you want by this command
$data = $data->addSelect(DB::raw("'fakeValue' as fakeColumn"));

$data = $data->orderBy('items.id')->get();
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 12):

You will want to create a model for your items table and query it that way. Using eloquent, you can create columns on the fly by adding column names to the $appends property and then defining a model attribute.

```
php artisan make:model Item
```

Any model automatically looks for a table that is the plural of the model name (Item looks for 'items'). In the Item model, add the following lines

```
/**
 * Append custom columns to the model
 * 
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['type'];

/**
 * Define the type column to every Item object instance
 * 
 * @return string
 */
public function getTypeAttribute()
{
    return 'car';
}
```

Now update your query to use the model instead of DB::select. Make sure to use the model at the top of your controller

```
use App\Item; 

....

$items = Item::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                       ->join('items_categories', 'items.item_category_id', '=', 'items_categories.category_id')
                       ->select( 
                                 'items.id as items___item_id',
                                 'items.item_title as items___item_title',
                                 'items_categories.id as items_categories___category_id',
                                 'items_categories.title as items_categories___category_title',
                               )
                       ->take(20)->get();
```

You need to add get() as the final method when using a Model for it to return a collection vs. DB::select.

Comment: Thanks, any chance to achieve this without the model part? I mean I have a model items, but I need to do this specific thing only in one case, so, this would be an overkill.

Comment: The line where you mentioned adding 'type' = 'car' should work just fine but the the model really is the best way to do this. You are already using Eloquent and just replacing a DB::select with a model call. Nothing is overkill if it works and is clean!

Comment: Hmm, if I try `'type' = 'car'` I am getting `syntax error, unexpected '=' ` and if I try `'type = car'` I am getting `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type = car' `

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact syntax to do it inline, but what you mentioned is on the right track. Or you could just add the model file and the 2 methods I mentioned and be done with it! I have you the solution and your still not satisfied for some reason

Comment: I need to know how to do it in the current statement. I am getting syntax errors right now.

Comment: For now I consider it as a Laravel bug. I will alter the results via php in my later code (which will slow down my code execution, but whatever), but it's weird you cannot create a custom field with a value during a select. Using eloquent models in my situation is quite slow - I am showing here only a fraction of my query - for simplification - and the number of rows I am getting is bigger than 20, of course ;) For some reason, the type = car is in separate array/object category, and everything is much more complicated on the output part. toArray is not helping either.

Comment: I haven't done it in raw SQL in a while, but just remembered. Change 'type' = 'car' to 'car' as type

Comment: I am getting `syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)`. maybe it's because I am using a join? Or maybe I need to use DB::raw(something something) inside of the select? Any idea how to do that?

Comment: This is the theory behind it. Might need to play around with it a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097150/add-a-temporary-column-with-a-value

Comment: Solved it by myself ;) check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution for this problem, hope it helps somebody else in the future.

```
$items = DB::table('items')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                           ->join('items_categories', 'items.item_category_id', '=', 'items_categories.category_id')
                           ->select(DB::raw('"car" AS type, 
                                             items.id as items___item_id,
                                             items.item_title as items___item_title,
                                             items_categories.id as items_categories___category_id,
                                             items_categories.title as items_categories___category_title
                                            ')
                                   )
                           ->take(20);
```

Comment: You don't need to put all your selects into the `DB::raw()`, it is enough to put `DB::raw('"car" AS type')` in a raw query.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same requirement, I know it is late but it might help someone in the future:

Here is my code how to a add a custom field in Laravel eloquent model

```
$searchResults = Blog::with('categories')
                ->where('title', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
                ->select(['*', DB::raw("'{$keyword}' as keyword")])
                ->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yep you can add a 'fixed' column neatly using the `selectRaw` method:

```
$items = DB::table('items')
   ->select('id','item_title')
   ->selectRaw("'car' AS type");
```

Answer (score 0):

i implement it sth like this sample

```
    $first = Message::where('from_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('to_id', '=', $id)->get();
    foreach ($first as $f)
        $f->is_sent = true;

    $second = Message::where('from_id', '=', $id)
        ->where('to_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    foreach ($second as $s)
        $s->is_sent = false;

    $chats = $first->merge($second)
        ->sortBy('created_at');

    return $chats->toJson();
```

you can do it by for eachafter get() method